# Why aren't the Imperial level names displaying correctly after an update?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Since updating Tiny Death Star, the two new Imperial levels just show "???" instead of the name of the level.  The dude in the upper right corner is all "???", no words.  The Imperial tasks just read as "???", no words.

I have tried forcing the app to shut down, as well as cycling my iPhone 5 on and off.  Nothing has worked.  Has anyone else had this problem?  Is there any known fix?  Pretty much anything that was new with the new update just shows up as "???" instead of words.  My sons game on his iPad 2 works fine with the update.

Comment: Hmmmm... Usually all the stuff you've tried, works (restarting, force quit, etc). The only thing I could think of is deleting and reinstalling the app but then you'd lose your progress, so that's not really a solution.

Comment: Referring to @Catija's suggestion, maybe you could synchronise your game progress to Facebook first before deleting and reinstalling the app. (P/S: I can't reply with a comment because I don't have enough reputation. So sorry if I am doing this wrongly)

Comment: it happens on android too, so probably its not your iphone

Comment: Android has been completely screwed up since the last update, and there have been no updates since.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star):

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

If you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming**.

As you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Comment: Note: this answer is a [community-proposed solution](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13064/28182) for unresolved Tiny Death Star bug questions.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bug to me, best choice is to write a review on the app store and hope it gets fixed.